# EFCore 3 Dynamic DbSet

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core

I'd like to declare a dynamic DbSet to my DbContext class in order to make custom raw queries without specifying a custom class, like so :

```
public partial class MyContext: DbContext
{
    public DbSet<dynamic> DynamicEntity { get; set; }
```

querying like the following

```
List<dynamic> dynamicResult = await dbContext.DynamicEntity
.FromSqlInterpolated($@"
    select [col1], [col2], ...
    from table1
    ")
.ToListAsync();
```

This configuration does not seems to work since i'm getting this runtime error:

> System.InvalidOperationException: The key {'TempId'} cis defined on the entity type 'object', not 'MyCustomView'.

It is possible to do that without other libraries (like DynamicLinq)?

Answer (score 1):

You can't use dynamic like a type for DbSet.

If you want creating custom SQL queries in EF Core you can use `ExecuteSqlCommand` method.

Here is an example:

```
using(var context = new SampleContext())
{
    var commandText = "INSERT Categories (CategoryName) VALUES (@CategoryName)";
    var name = new SqlParameter("@CategoryName", "Test");
    context.Database.ExecuteSqlRaw(commandText, name);
}
```

Comment: The only true is that the dynamic cannot be used as type for `DbSet`. However `ExecuteSql` *cannot* be used to execute **queries** and get the result set back, only *commands*, so the rest is not a solution. Which doesn't exist anyway.

Comment: Thank you for your proposal but, as Ivan stated i'm looking for a generic solution to get a dataset back.